# Truncate with a twist

Tags: column, email

I've been browsing this site for two days now with no avail to my problem.

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise site with Designer Workflows only. This site for reasons I cannot go into is very limited and doesn't have functionality as you would with some other premise situation. Also note that there is no switching, there is no moving, it is what it is.

So what I'm working with is a word document is created on Premise. This document is sent out to ANOTHER SharePoint 2013 on Premise site that has Nintex and Designer Workflow options.

From Site B I use nintex to convert DOC to PDF and now I need it to email to the user that created it. When moving the file it comes over with just the column "name". The document is labeled one of the following to prevent over writing.  "emailES" "emailCO" "emailPU" "emailSO" "emailSC".

Using this I tried to make a column that would truncate the last 2 characters and leave the email in place. So I need it to go from appleseed@site.comES to appleseed@site.com. From there it's easy I simply use the name as the email to send to. But I can't wrap my head around removing the last two and leaving email in place.

I'm sure this is incredibly easy, but maybe this week isn't my week. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new calculated column to include the following, I believe it will give you the string that you're hoping to preserve:

=LEFT(Name,LEN(Name)-2)

Cheers!